# Build a library using Closure Library

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm trying to "build" my project using Closure Library; Sadly, after many tests I can't build something without problems. My project is a library, so I haven't got an entry point or anything like that, most of the code is made of objects and functions for the user.

I've got a project like that:

```
 - build
      - build.sh
      - compiler.jar
 - libs
      - closure-library
 - src
```

My **build.sh** file:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js_output_file out.js `find ../src/ -name '*.js'`
```

With this command line I've got the error:`goog.require('goog.vec.Vec2');`; So I think I need to include google closure library in this line, right?

So, I've tried to change my build.sh to something like that (added closure-library folder):

```
java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js_output_file out.js `find ../src/ ../libs/closure-library/closure/ -name '*.js'`
```

With this script, I've got many error from the closure library like that:

```
../libs/closure-library/closure/goog/i18n/datetimeformat_test.js:572: ERROR - This style of octal literal is not supported in strict mode.
  var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 11 - 1, 01, 11, 0, 1));
```

And my resulting file (out.js) haven't got all my library's functions. I'm not sure to understand where is the problem.

- Did I really have to include google closure in the build part?
- I'm working on a Javascript library so I haven't got an entry point and all the code must be included in the resulting file. So, how can I do that?

Thanks for your time!

**Edit:**
I've tried something different: removing all lines like "goog.require('goog.vec.Mat4');" from my library. The build is done successfully but my simulation didn't work anymore: `Cannot read property 'Mat4' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is documented on the GitHub wiki under [Manage Closure Dependencies](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Manage-Closure-Dependencies)

## Determining Dependencies

### 1. Your Library Source Contains `goog.provide` Statements

In this case you would use `--only_closure_dependencies` combined with `--closure_entry_point` flags. Your "entry" points are any class in your library from which you want to calculate dependencies. You can have multiple entry points.

### 2. Your Library Source Does Not Contain `goog.provide` Statements

Use the `--manage_closure_dependencies` flag. This instructs the compiler to include any JS file which does not contain a `goog.provide` statement in the output and to calculate all needed dependencies based on the `goog.require` statements in those files.

## Providing Files To The Compiler

Closure-compiler's `--js` input flags can specify minimatch glob style patterns and this is the preferred method for providing Closure-library files as input. If you are using the `--manage_closure_dependencies` option, you must exclude the Closure-library test files.

Example:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level=SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
    --js_output_file=out.js
    --manage_closure_dependencies
    --js='../src/**.js'
    --js='../libs/closure-library/**.js'
    --js='!../libs/closure-library/**_test.js'
```

Comment: Great! I was on the closure website so I didn't found it. Thank you!